# How to install ubuntu unity

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, mate

How to install ubuntu unity with in ubuntu mate?

Tried installing via terminal sudo and was unsuccessful. Hardware is raspberry pi 3.

Comment: You don’t mention how it was unsuccessful. A pi is not likely to have sufficient hardware to run unity.

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not support Linux. Only as a target platform. Editor platform is Windows.
They had an experimental version some time ago, but that is mostly dead. I also wanted to have that but it's Windows you need for Unity.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/577249/linux-support-a-thing-or-not.html

There were official releases, but this forum page is from the stoneage:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/